Metropolis-Hastings Proposal Distribution multiplied by scalar. How does this affect the Hastings Ratio?
So, if I propose $\theta^*$ from $\text{Dirichlet}(\theta_i \times \tau)$, where $\tau$ is some scalar, does the Metropolis-Hastings atio need to account for that scalar i.e.
$$\text{Dirichlet}(\theta_i|\theta^*\times\tau) \big/ \text{Dirichlet}(\theta^*|\theta_i \times\tau)$$
or should I drop the $\tau$'s from the Metropolis-Hastings ratio? I went through the proof for the MH algorithm and this is not immediately clear.

Yes. Any time you change the distribution, you change the ratio. In some rare cases, changes in distribution do not produce a change in ratio but that is quite rare. I don't think your change of scale of the dirichlet causes a full simplification

For a function $f(\cdot)$ proportional to the probability density of interest, and a proposal function $g ( \cdot ∣ \cdot )$ proportional to a conditional density, the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm operates with the Markov kernel $K( \cdot ∣ \cdot )$ defined as
$$K(\theta'|\theta)=\alpha(\theta'|\theta)g(\theta'|\theta)+(1-\bar\alpha(\theta))\delta_\theta(\theta')$$
where $\delta_\theta$ denotes the Dirac mass in $\theta$ and
$$\alpha =\dfrac{f(\theta')/f(\theta)}{g(\theta'|\theta)/g(\theta|\theta')}\wedge 1$$
with
$$\bar\alpha(\theta) = \int \left\{\dfrac{f(\theta')/f(\theta)}{g(\theta'|\theta)/g(\theta|\theta')}\wedge 1\right\} g(\theta'|\theta)\,\text d\theta'$$
Therefore, when $g(\theta'|\theta)$ corresponds to the density of the Dirichlet $\mathcal D_p(\tau\theta)$ distribution with $\tau>0$, the ratio $g(\theta'|\theta)/g(\theta|\theta')$ writes as
$$\frac{\Gamma(\tau\sum_{i=1}^p\theta_i)}{\Gamma(\tau\sum_{i=1}^p\theta'_i)}\prod_{i=1}^p \frac{\Gamma(\tau\theta'_i)\,(\theta')_i^{\tau\theta_i-1}}{\Gamma(\tau\theta_i)\,\theta_i^{\tau(\theta')_i-1}}$$
and there is no immediate simplification.

Thank you. This is indeed equal to the ratio I had written: Dirichlet(θi|θ∗×τ)/Dirichlet(θ∗|θi×τ)
